# How to convert array to string in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Here is my code

```
<?php
        rsort($max_k);
        for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) // Only loop 10 times.
        //echo $max_k[$i] . "<br>";
        $newArray = array_slice($max_k, 0, 10, true);

        echo ($newArray) ;

      ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of Debugger Class

```
App::uses('Debugger','Utility');
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13);
$arrayToString = Debugger::exportVar($array);
echo $arrayToString;

//Result:
//array( (int) 0 => (int) 1, (int) 1 => (int) 2, (int) 2 => (int) 3, (int) 3 => (int) 4, (int) 4 => (int) 5 )
```

link: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging.html#Debugger::exportVar

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `print_r($newArray)`

you may use foreach() for accessing individual elements as needed according to your program logic.
Hope this is enough for the task. Do comment if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following test code:

```
$max_k=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13);
$newArray=array_slice($max_k, 0, 10, true);
```

In PHP you can produce a readable output from data structures in different ways. One of the oldest functions is print_r (php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php):

```
print_r($newArray);
```

produces the output:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 2
  [2] => 3
  [3] => 4
  [4] => 5
  [5] => 6
  [6] => 7
  [7] => 8
  [8] => 9
  [9] => 10
)
```

The next possibility is var_dump (php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php), which takes one or more variables to display with value and structure:

```
var_dump($newArray);
```

One of my favourites is var_export (php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php):

```
var_export($newArray);
```

which creates:

```
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 3,
  3 => 4,
  4 => 5,
  5 => 6,
  6 => 7,
  7 => 8,
  8 => 9,
  9 => 10,
)
```

Best feature of var_export is, that it supports a second boolean parameter. When set to true, it will return the readable version as a string. So you can for example log the output to a file instead of printing:

```
$output=var_export($newArray, true);
print $output;
```

Result:

```
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 3,
  3 => 4,
  4 => 5,
  5 => 6,
  6 => 7,
  7 => 8,
  8 => 9,
  9 => 10,
)
```

Hope that helps.

PS: The php.net site has a cool feature: if you enter a search string after the php.net like:

```
php.net/var_dump
```

you will be sent to the man page of that function, if it exists or see a list of similar results, if there is no function with that name :)